# Date + 3 month intervat mysql Column

Tags: mysql

I have a tble which has fromdate and todate fields. I have been trying to fetch data for a particular date.

Below is the query that i have been trying with no luck,

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM install
 WHERE customer != ''
   AND billtype = 'QUARTERLY'
   AND (STR_TO_DATE (fromdate, ' %m-%Y') + INTERVAL 3 MONTH=STR_TO_DATE('01-01-2018', ' %m-%Y'))
```

For Example

if he user selects january month of 2019, any row with fromdate + 3 months should come up.
                                Any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using date inequalities, which avoid the calls to `STR_TO_DATE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM install
WHERE
    customer <> '' AND
    billtype = 'QUARTERLY' AND
    DATE_ADD(fromdate, INTERVAL 3 MONTH) BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-01-31';
```

FYI your current syntax is off, which is why it won't work as you expected.

But actually, a better way to express your logic would be to *subtract* 3 months from January 2018:

```
SELECT *
FROM install
WHERE
    customer <> '' AND
    billtype = 'QUARTERLY' AND
    fromdate BETWEEN '2017-10-01' AND '2017-10-31';
```

This version of the query is also SARGable, meaning that an index involving the `fromdate` column could still be used.